# Role of physics in quantum computing

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I am a physics graduate student and I am very interested in quantum computing, having taken two courses so far. My research advisor is a Materials Physicist and he says that there is really no role in quantum computing for a physicist besides improving the hardware. I pointed out that superposition and entanglement are both fundamental physical concepts. Another would be the unitary transformations. He says this is true but you don't need physics really to develop any software or algorithms, etc. I was wondering what opinions the quantum computing community has on this. Is there a role for a physicist?

Comment: Hello and welcome. There are many roles outside of the hardware that physicists can be useful for in quantum computing. First, developping more efficient quantum error correction scheme is really at the boundary between physics, math and computer science. Then, many fundamental quantum effects can be useful to develop new kind of algorithms. One example I have in mind are the superposition of causal orders which allows to develop new kinds of computational tasks.

Comment: Hi Anne! thanks for your question, unfortunately, QC.SE isn't really the right forum for folks looking for opinion-based answers. Check out our on-topic help page for more info https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the response @MarcoFellous-Asiani. I will look that up.

Comment: Sorry @Condo I didn't realize this was the wrong place.

Comment: @Anne no worries! Also, there are lots of quantum computing industry people on Twitter these days... might be worth asking there.

Comment: I think it’s a good question at heart.  You might be able to edit this to make it less likely to be opinionated. For example: “What are open problems in quantum computing from a *physics* perspective, less so than a computer science perspective?” There are lots of really good open problems that physicists might grok much more intuitively than computer scientists..